# Git: Is there a way to git stash but be able to specify a branch name?

Tags: git, branch, reset

I'm working along with some changes and I'm not sure about them. They may be the right way to proceed, but maybe I'm going down the wrong path. I want to save my work just in case I am doing the right thing but not continue with this line of development right now and return to where I was a half hour ago for example. Basically, do a stash but make the stash commit a real branch with a descriptive name.

something like

```
git stash save-stuff  // not a valid command
```

what I've been doing requires multiple commands

```
git commit -a -m 'not sure this is where I want to go'
git checkout -b save-stuff
git checkout original-branch // return to original branch
git reset --hard HEAD~1 // I don't always do this one.
```

This causes me displeasure.

Comment: I recommend *avoiding* `git stash` as it is full of traps for the unwary (and sometimes even for the wary). Make a new branch now, then commit (in that order to make things easier). That is, `git checkout -b save-stuff` then `git add` and `git commit` as usual. Creating and switching to a new branch (either `git branch` then `git checkout`/`git switch`, or all in one with `git checkout -b`/`git switch -c`) is always allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps :

- `git stash` has a subcommand [`git stash create`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-create), which basically creates the same commit as `git stash` but doesn't update the stash and does not touch your index or worktree
- `git update-ref` allows you to "update" a ref (for example : branch) without it being the current active branch

You can combine the two, either in a script :

```
# file git-snap:

#!/bin/bash

if git diff -s --exit-code HEAD; then
    echo " --- worktree is clean, nothing to save"
    exit 0
fi

# get name of active branch, to update a branch named wip/<branch> :
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
ref="refs/heads/wip/$branch"

# call git stash create:
sha=$(git stash create)
# update a branch named 'wip/<branch>' :
git update-ref -m "save wip on $branch" "$ref" "$sha"

git log --oneline -1 "$ref"
```

(if you place the above `git-snap` script on your PATH, you can then simply invoke `git snap`)

or if you are into one liners :

```
git update-ref refs/heads/mystash $(git stash create)
```

Comment: I assume that you want `if git diff -s --exit-code HEAD` instead of `if [ git diff -s --exit-code HEAD ]`?

Comment: @AndreasLouv: correct, fixed. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I think the answer is "no", there is no single git command that will do what I want :) It's easy enough to make a shell command which I will have to do. "git-save"

Answer (score 1):

Git history is *always* hierarchical, and that applies to `git stash` as well. `git stash` creates a new commit, relative to a specific *commit*, rather than a branch. As such, there is no need to save a Git stash with a specific name; in doing so, you would literally be *creating* a branch.

If you want to be able save a temporary piece of work that you are not confident is correct, the best thing to do would be to make use of a **branch**. Doing so will allow you, and anyone else working on the repository (should you push the branch to the origin), to be able to refer back to this point in time easily. You can make subsequent changes to this branch if your approach is found to be correct, and even squash the changes to make it seem like the questionable commit never existed.

Keep in mind that there is nothing stopping you from checking out an individual *commit* -- even on a branch that you are currently working on. This will allow you to revert back should you need to, and you can continue working from this old commit, even pushing to the same branch if desired.

Comment: Yes, I know about that but it takes 4 commands do that which I listed above. I'm asking if there is a one-liner that does all that. I dislike git stash because of the lack of descriptive name.